# ‘.”line”’ not accepted as valid syntax by jq - "unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER"

Tags: json, linux, bash, macos, shell

I'm trying to make a GET request with curl in a bash file.
So I call curl, and get a JSON response from my server, and I try to get the object **line** which is part of the response, and I do so with **jq**, so I can print the value. 
But its not working.

My response is something like this:

```
{"line":"Azul", "id":"j3453j45n35", "lat":"39.091937", "long":"-9.265441"}
```

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    cmd=$(curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/cards/exists/1 | jq ‘.”line”’) 
    sleep 2
done
```

The result:

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
>   ‘.”line”’
>   jq: 1 compile error
>   (23) Failed writing body

Whats going wrong?
I followed plenty of responses people advised online, but I keep getting the same response.
My json object seems to be correct.
I'm running this file on MacOS Sierra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- You're using **non-ASCII quotes** (`‘ ” ” ’`), which `jq` doesn't understand:

  - Replace them with their ASCII equivalents: `' " " '`
  - On macOS, avoid a text editor such as the standard `TextEdit.app` that has the "smart quotes" feature turned on, or turn that feature off via the menu system: `Edit > Substitutions > Smart Quotes`
    It is this feature that replaces ASCII quoting chars. with their non-ASCII, typographical equivalents, *as you type*.
  - Generally, consider using a dedicated source-code editor for editing your code, such as Visual Studio Code (free) or Atom (free) or Sublime Text (paid).
- **Your `curl` command includes *header* output (`-i`)**, which `jq` chokes on - simply omit the `-i`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
    cmd=$(curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8080/cards/exists/1' |
            jq '.line') 
    sleep 2
done
```

While `'."line"'` would have worked too, there's no need for the extra layer of quoting for simple property names like that.

Also, it's better to enclose strings that you want to be interpreted *literally* in `'...'` in the shell.